# How to trigger SwiftUI animation via change of non-State variable

Tags: animation, swiftui

It's easy to have an animation begin when a view appears, by using `.onAppear()`. But I'd like to perform a repeating animation whenever one of the view's non-State variables changes. An example:

Here is a view that I would like to "throb" whenever its `throbbing` parameter, set externally, is `true`:

```
struct MyCircle: View {
    var throbbing: Bool
    @State var scale = 1.0
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 100 * scale, height: 100 * scale)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .animation(.easeInOut.repeatForever(), value: scale)
            .onAppear { scale = 1.2 }
    }
}
```

Currently the code begins throbbing immediately, regardless of the `throbbing` variable.

But imagine this scenario:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var throb: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Throb: \(throb ? "ON" : "OFF")") { throb.toggle() }
            MyCircle(throbbing: throb)
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: Throbbing Circle]

Any ideas how I can modify MyCircle so that the throbbing starts when the button is tapped and ends when it is tapped again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onChange` to watch `throbbing` and then assign an animation. If true, add a repeating animation, and if false, just animate back to the original scale size:

```
struct MyCircle: View {
    var throbbing: Bool
    @State private var scale : CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .scaleEffect(1 + scale)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .onChange(of: throbbing) { newValue in
                if newValue {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut.repeatForever()) {
                        scale = 0.2
                    }
                } else {
                    withAnimation {
                        scale = 0
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow - it's that simple! onChange was one of my first thoughts, but somehow I thought it was only for @State variables. Thanks!

Comment: Saxophonists unite in the power of SwiftUI...

Answer (score 0):

There're two interesting things that i've just found when trying to achieve yours target.

- Animation will be added when the `value` changed
- Animation that added to the view cannot be removed, and we need to drop the animated view from the view hiearachy by remove its `id`, new view will be created with zero animations.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var throbbling = false
    @State var circleId = UUID()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Throbbling", isOn: $throbbling)
            circle.id(circleId)
                .scaleEffect(throbbling ? 1.2 : 1.0)
                .animation(.easeInOut.repeatForever(), value: throbbling)
                .onChange(of: throbbling) { newValue in
                    if newValue == false {
                        circleId = UUID()
                    }
                }
        }.padding()
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var circle: some View {
        Circle().fill(.green).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```